# Newman: array instead of string

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I am trying to run Postman tests in Newman. One of my tests sends POST request with following data:

```
{ 
  "additionalSizes": "[]",
  "brand": "Some Brand",
  "color": "#5484ed",
  "model": "Some Model",
  "size": "80",
  "sizeType": "eu",
  "type": "some type"
}
```

For some resosons newman sends parameter "size" as array ("size":{"1":"80"}) instead sending it as string ("size":"80") like in Postman.

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: The question is: why it happens ? and how it can be fixed? I need this parameter as a string

Comment: Try removing the hashtag from color, see if it helps

Comment: removing hash from color does not helped